# flask runserver.py "no module name config"

Tags: python, flask

I am making a sms api in flask. When I tried to run it through python runserver.py it says no module name config but I have that file. It contains api_version, secret_key and all. I dont know whats wrong. Can anyone help me. Its config.py.BAK

Answer (score 0):

In order to import a python file, it should have an extension `.py`. So rename the file `config.py.BAK` to `config.py` and try again.

Comment: I did it but it still says the same.